# O que fazer quando postamos um comentário na pergunta e acabamos já resolvendo a questão?

Tags: suporte

Quando postamos um comentário na pergunta, questionando algo para que possamos responder, mas o perguntador acaba descobrindo a resposta com nosso comentário, mesmo assim formalizamos a resposta como "resposta"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, formaliza como resposta. Se possível, desenvolva mais a explicação. Vale a pena citar o comentário do autor da pergunta que confirmou sua hipótese.

E quem perguntou, se achar que a resposta resolve mesmo o problema, deve marcá-la como aceita.

Comment: Estou falando pra todos em termos gerais, já vi que nesse caso específico você já postou a resposta.

Comment: Sim, eu deduzi que seria importante formalizar, mas mesmo assim postei aqui para tirar essa dúvida. Obrigado pela resposta!